# convert VALUE from JSON format to LIST

Tags: python, json, list

from json value below:

```
result_dict = [{"result": 100},
               {"result": 200},
               {"result": 300},
               {"result": 400}
                ]
print(result_dict)
```

i want to convert to become List.
the expected output should be like this:

```
a = [100, 200, 300, 400]
or
a = [[100],[200],[300],[400]]
```

Is anyone can show some Python code to do it? Thank you in advance,

Comment: `[d['result'] for d in result_dict]` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[100, 200, 300, 400] Generated using

```
[d['result'] for d in result_dict]
```

[[100], [200], [300], [400]]  Generated using

```
[list(val.values()) for val in result_dict]
```

Final Code

```
result_dict = [{"result": 100},
               {"result": 200},
               {"result": 300},
               {"result": 400}
                ]
# by RomanPerekhrest
b=[d['result'] for d in result_dict]
print(b)

a=[list(val.values()) for val in result_dict]
print(a)
```

Output

```
[100, 200, 300, 400]
[[100], [200], [300], [400]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Fisrt iterate through the dictionary and then add data to a list.

```
result_dict = [{"result": 100},
               {"result": 200},
               {"result": 300},
               {"result": 400}
                ]
print([data["result"] for data in result_dict])
print([[data["result"]] for data in result_dict])
```

Output

```
[100, 200, 300, 400]
[[100], [200], [300], [400]]
```